# how to change src fo image element by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the src of an image element, for that I use this code, but it doesn't work when I click "add" button, please help.....

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Edit Home Page</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function setimgsrc()
            {
                $('#image').attr("src",document.getElementById("src").val());
            };
            </script>
    </head>    
 <body>      
   <div class='center-block'>                          
<label >course title: </label>             
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="enter title for this course" >             
<br> <label >course description: </label>             
<input type="text" id="des" name="des" placeholder="enter decription for this course" >             
<br> <label >image source : </label>             
<input type='text' id='src' name='src' >             
<input type='button' class='btn' onclick='setimgsrc()' value='add'>             <br> <img  id='image' style='width:500px; height:500px' >                     </div>     
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What "*doesn't work*" about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include jquery library. 
your head section should be

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function setimgsrc()
        {
           var getImage = $('#src').val();             
           $('#image').attr("src", getImage);
        };
        </script>
```

If you do not want to use jquery then you should rewrite setimgsrc() function as below

function setimgsrc()
            {

```
            var getImage = document.getElementById("src").value;            
            document.getElementById("image").src = getImage;                
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added [jquery library](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.j) and here is the updated code:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Edit Home Page</title>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
  function setimgsrc()
  {
   $('#image').attr("src",$("#src").val());
  };
 </script>
</head>    
<body>      
 <div class='center-block'>                          
  <label >course title: </label>             
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="enter title for this course" >             
  <br> <label >course description: </label>             
  <input type="text" id="des" name="des" placeholder="enter decription for this course" >             
  <br> <label >image source : </label>             
  <input type='text' id='src' name='src' >             
  <input type='button' class='btn' onclick='setimgsrc()' value='add'>             
  <br> 
  <img  id='image' style='width:500px; height:500px' >                     
 </div>     
</body> 
</html>
```